# XPATH Contain() Function Not Working for Multiple <div> Tags with Same Name

Tags: xpath, screen-scraping, contains

I am trying to scrape the following section (only an excerpt) of an XML code. The second form-item is what I'm trying to scrape:

```
<div class="form-item">
<a href="http://www.avaopera.org" target="_blank" rel="" class="">http://www.avaopera.org</a>
</div>
<div class="form-item">
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('*[block of text]*')
</script>
<a href="mailto:ademarco@avaopera.org">ademarco@avaopera.org</a>
</div>
```

I used the following xpath query with the contain function because there are multiple form-item tags: `//div[@class='form-item' and contains(.,'@')]/a/text()`

This query does not work. I tried removing `/a/text()` which displays the text within the `<script>` but not the  tag text.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please use a code block next time. Your code was interpreted as markup and it was quite hard to get it back. More over, < and > characters were stripped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're targeting the text within the `<div>` instead of the text within the `<a>`, if I understand your goal correctly.

Try using `//div[@class='form-item' and contains(a/text(),'@')]/a/text()` instead, as this will search the child `<a>` element within the `<div>` and not its parent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The code you suggested does not return any data. Neither does this return anything: `//div[@class='form-item' and contains(a/@href,'@')]` I have tried a whole bunch of other combinations, but for whatever reason I am not able to access the code within the `<a>` block! Any inputs?

Comment: I used the XPath given in my answer and got back the `<div>` block containing the email address from the XML supplied in  your question, so yes it does return data. Looks like you're doing something run in the implementation of it.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Does it make a difference that I'm calling my XPATH commands from a Spreadsheet using the importXML command? If so, what would be (a better) alternative to doing that? Thanks!

Comment: Is the XML you supplied the entirety of what you're trying to query? If so then it will fail because it is not a complete XML, no beginning/end tags. I added these for my test as I assumed this was only an excerpt. If you think this is related to where you're calling it from, try a simpler test with mock data in your spreadsheet and ensure that works first.

Comment: So, this is the link to the website that I am querying: http://www.philaculture.org/resources/member-directory/11185/academy-vocal-arts. Can you tell me if your code works when you query the website directly?

Comment: I don't think you're quite understanding what I'm saying... XPath must be applied to valid XML. So however you're getting the data from the page, it needs to be in a valid block with beginning and ending tags, or no query will work at all (and you should be getting an error). The XPath I supplied works for your given snippet which I corrected to be valid xml in my test.

Comment: The XML I supplied is just an excerpt. Here's what I do: On Spreadsheet, in one cell (say A1) I have the link to the website, and in another cell (say B1) I have the XPATH query. Now, in a third cell I type `=importXML(A1,B1)`.

Comment: Right. And you're not importing a proper XML.

Comment: I'm very new to XML and scraping. If you could show in brief how that is done, or if you could provide a link to a tutorial that explains it, I would appreciate it a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I understood what is happening. I should have definitely told you what is in the first form-item. Please look at it and you'll understand why the XPATH does not return any data. The contains functions check the first `<a>` tag. How do I direct the XPATH query to the second form-item?